# How to get all post list in wordpress admin?

Tags: php, plugins, wordpress, wordpress-theming

i am creating a plugin. 
i want to get all post like title and url. Not on frontpage just admin panel.
when i try to use this but not working

```
<?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => -1); 
$posts= get_posts( $args );
if ($posts) {
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        setup_postdata($post);
        the_title();
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this

```
<?php
global $post;
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : 
  setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach;
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: Great Thank you 
i have a question if i want to yoast title it is possible ?

Comment: Can you clarify the question?

Comment: title from yoast is solved ...but
any way to fetch limited number of post ? i want show only 20 post

Comment: then change $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 20 );

Answer (score 2):

You must pass a reference to the `global $post` variable, otherwise functions like `the_title()` don't work properly. So above `$args`:

```
global $post;
$args = array( 'numberposts' => -1); 
$posts= get_posts( $args );
if ($posts) {
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        setup_postdata($post);
        the_title();
    }
}
wp_reset_postdata()
```

Also, use `wp_reset_postdata()` to restore globals to the original state when complete.

> • [More Information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata)

Comment: Great thank you ...i have a question if i want to yoast title it is possible ?

Comment: any way to fetch limited number of post ? i want show only 20 post